# How to Echo Datas From Mysql Properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mini game which is written in PHP. I want to build a highscore section for it. But I can't echo datas properly. My database

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+------+
| UserID | Username | Password                         | EmailAddress        | win  | lost |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+------+
|      1 | utku     | e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e | utku@utku.com       |    3 |    6 |
|      2 | utku2    | e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e | utku@sda.com        |    5 |   15 |
|      3 | utku3    | e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e | sad                 |    0 |    0 |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+------+
```

I'm trying to echo them with this code (I found it in another question's topic)

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>

<?
$query="SELECT Username,win,lost FROM users ORDER BY win";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr><br>';
}
?>
```

It prints datas like this

```
utku3utku30000
utkuutku3366
utku2utku2551515
```

But I want to print them in this form

```
Username  Win  Lost
utku2      5    15
utku       3    6
utku3      0    0
```

How can I do it. I'm new on PHP

Comment: The doc tell you [`array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)  and for `MYSQL_BOTH`: `By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.` Thats why you get each column twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not print `tr, td` without `table` tag. Also you did not added `th`. Can try this

```
echo '<table><tr><th>User Name</th><th>Win</th><th>Lost</th></tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['Username'].'</td><td>'.$row['win'].'</td><td>'.$row['lost'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I think the main problem is everything getting echo'd twice

Comment: it still prints values twice

Comment: Updated my post @JayGatsby. Hope now it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `mysql_` as it is outdated and will be removed in future versions of php.
You should switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. ([Overview of the MySQL PHP drivers > Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php))

Your problem is:
[`array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

MYSQL_BOTH: `[...]By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.[...]`

That's why you get each column twice.

A quick fix would be using `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_ASSOC`:

```
mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the foreach loop because the while loop is doing the recursive iteraction, that's why you have twice results:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field['Username']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field['win']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field['lost']) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr><br>';
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's nothing to do with it. The while loop goes through each row, whereas the foreach goes through each field